# gitignore everything but certain extencions and also directories

Tags: git

I want to be able to make Git ignore everything but certain types of extensions.
This is my current `.gitignore` file:

```
# ignore everything
*
# but desired files
!*.vhd
!*.tcl
!*.py
!*.cpp
!*.c
!*.tex
!*.asm
!*.qpf
```

The problem is that now Git also ignores patterns like this `some/directory/somefile.vhd`

If I add `!*/`now  directories starting with dot are not ignored.

How can I prevent that from happening?

I also tried adding two asterisks but the result was the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the directory is ignored, all files inside will be ignored too. You can exclude the directories with the following:

```
*
!*/
.*/
!*.vhd
!*.tcl
```

Etc. Including the directories this way just means that those directories will be checked for non-ignored files. Directories are not actually included in Git.